# Receive keys and the values without knowledge of key names

Tags: dictionary, pymongo

I am a beginner and am working with pymongo where the data to be received could be at different levels of nesting (values inside objects) the structure of data can be considered as:

```
ID: value1
partNumber: Object
partNumber.current: value2
partNumber.noWhite: value3
partNumber.visualSimilar: Array
partNumber.visualSimilar.0:value4
partNumber.visualSimilar.1:value5
Media: Object
Media.supplier:value6
Media.validated: value7
```

This is just a sample; the real data is very large. What I want is to be able to extract data in the following format without prior knowledge of keys of the collection in the database as there are more than 45:

[image]

What I am not understanding is what would be the optimal way know if I am to store the value against a key as is or as a nested dictionary. For now I can omit any object inside objects.

Comment: Please post what you have tried as your question isn't clear. Also always post text not images.